# Launching Chrome and passing the url with selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium for the first time:
below is my basic Code to launch the chrome and pass the google url:

```
public class first {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe");
        WebDriver dr1= new ChromeDriver(); ;
        String baseurl = "http://www.google.com/";
        dr1.get(baseurl);
        
    }
}
```

After executing it is launching the browser but not sending the url to it.
below is the error i got in console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'D-113091507', ip: '172.16.195.19', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
    at first.first.main(first.java:12)
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Download the latest Chrome and `ChromeDriver` versions.

Comment: what is the chrome driver and browser version you are using?

Comment: I guess,  system property is pointing to chrome binary instead of chrome driver exe. Please make sure of it.

Comment: I don't know what OS you are currently using but this guide helped me a lot regarding the actual installation and path setup: [link](http://www.kenst.com/2015/03/installing-chromedriver-on-mac-osx/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

When you work with Selenium 3.x you have to download **chromedriver.exe** from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and save it in your machine. Next you have to mention the absolute path of the **chromedriver.exe** through `System.setProperty`. While you mention the absolute path of the **chromedriver.exe** through `System.setProperty` you have either provide front slashes "**/**" or esacpe the back slases "**\\**". Here is your own working code with some simple tweaks:

```
public class first 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/your_directory/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver dr1= new ChromeDriver(); ;
        String baseurl = "http://www.google.com/";
        dr1.get(baseurl);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 1909
Jun 05, 2017 11:49:15 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'D-113091507', ip: '172.16.195.19', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: Your chromedriver version seems `v2.9.248315`. Consider upgrading it to `v2.29` to work with Google Chrome 58.x Thanks

Comment: Hi Guys, stuck again at String baseurl = "https://login.yahoo.com/beta/";
  dr1.get(baseurl);
  WebElement email = dr1.findElement(By.id("login-username"));
  Actions builder = new Actions(dr1);
  dr1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  Actions newAction = builder.moveToElement(email).click().sendKeys(email,new String[]{"test@gmail.com"}); it is not passing the keys to the username field chrome, pls help me out.